# Heroism Spell removes Frightened's effect, or does Frightened's effect still exist but is just not effective due to immunity?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, fear

In one session, my character got Frightened because he failed a saving throw. Then my friend cast Heroism on my character, but after 1 minute the spell ran out.  My question is, after 1 minute will the Frightened effect still be there or is it negated when casting Heroism?

Comment: Hi, I think the linked duplicate answer deals with exactly the same situation that you experience with the only difference that here it is a paladin's aura creating the immunity instead of a spell, so I closed this as a duplicate (which is not bad, it helps people looking for specifically Heroism to find the answer).   Let us know if you think those answers do not answer your question.